# How to group by lowest value in field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in mysql that returns a resultset like this

```
ID1     ID2     string      date
14071   3031324 string 1    2016-08-10 21:29:39
14071   3054168 string 2    2016-08-10 21:33:26
14071   3054169 string 3    2016-08-10 21:33:26
14074   2938174 string 2    2016-08-10 21:14:48
14074   2938175 string 3    2016-08-10 21:14:48
14074   2938176 string 1    2016-08-10 21:14:48
14093   2954386 string 2    2016-08-10 21:17:22
14093   3035338 string 3    2016-08-10 21:30:19
```

I need to filter this to ruturn only the lins with the lowest ID2 for each ID1

```
14071   3031324 string 1    2016-08-10 21:29:39
14074   2938174 string 2    2016-08-10 21:14:48
14093   2954386 string 2    2016-08-10 21:17:22
```

thanks

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields. A date has a year _field_, a month _field_ etc.

Comment: @jarlh not sure how this comment contributes to the discussion

Comment: See it as general terminology advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select *
from t
where (id1, id2) in (select id1, min(id2) from t group by id1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `RANK()` the records partitioning as needed and selecting only the lowest rank:

```sql
SELECT ID1, ID2, string, date
FROM (
    SELECT ID1, ID2, string, date, RANK() over ( PARTITION BY ID1, ORDER BY ID2 ASC ) rank
    FROM {your_table}
)
WHERE rank = 1
```